# How to import module installed by pip to a custom directory

Tags: python, pip

I'm writing a plugin for an app, and found that packages I install with pip are apparently being ignored, so I'm trying to install them within my plugin's directory using

```
pip install --ignore-installed --install-option="--prefix=[plugins-folder]" [package-name]
```

This creates a folder structure `lib/python2.7/site-packages/[dependencies]` which is fine by me, except I can't figure out how to them import those dependencies. Even if I manage to import the main package, it will break because it can't find it's own dependencies which are also in that same directory structure.

Comment: If packages are being ignored, you should validate that the version of python you are using matches what you expect. It sounds to me like you may have multiple versions in play...

Comment: What app are you creating the plugin for, and how does the app import its plugins? You might need a specific directory structure for it to work.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should use virtual python environment. *virtualenv* for python2/python3 and *python3 -m venv* for python3.

You python environment seems orderless and you should isolate each environment for each python app.